# Is there a difference between \x{..} and \N{U+..}

Tags: perl

Is there a difference in using either `\x{..}` or `\N{U+..}` in a print statement?
To me they look like 2 ways of doing the same thing.
So what is the difference - if there is any?

Comment: Also see: https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1204017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"\x{...}"` and `"\N{U+...}"` always produce exactly the same string, meaning `"\x{...}" eq "\N{U+...}"` will always be true (for the same number).

However, since 5.12, the scalar created by `"\N{U+...}"` is guaranteed to use the `UTF8=1` internal storage format<sup>[1]</sup>, while the scalar created by `"\x{...}"` is not subject to any guarantee (and in fact uses the `UTF8=0` format when possible). This means that `utf8::upgrade` needs not be called on a scalar produced by `"\N{U+...}"` before passing it to (builtin or XS) functions that suffer from The Unicode Bug.<sup>[2]</sup>

In short, `"\N{U+...}"` is more likely to work correctly when dealing with Unicode Code Points, and `"\x{...}"` is more likely to work correctly when dealing with bytes.

---

1. The `UTF8=0` storage format support strings of 8-bit characters, while the `UTF8=1` storage format support strings of 32- or 64-bit characters (depending on the build).
2. This refers to code that considers two identical strings to be different because one is stored using `UTF8=0` format, and one is stored using the `UTF8=1` format). Code that assigns semantics to the storage format is buggy because Perl can and does freely convert strings between the two formats.

Comment: There is another difference on EBCDIC platforms, where `\x` will return the character represented by that byte in EBCDIC for bytes under FF, but `\N{U+...}` will return the same codepoint regardless of the internal representation.

Comment: @Grinnz, Thanks. Given that Perl probably isn't used an EBCDIC machines (it was broken long ago as a result of a lack of testing platform, and it only recently became supported again), I've leave the question as is. Your comment will suffice.